# Difference between modelling and testing association

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, statistical-significance, association-rules

I have data set with binary outcome, with 5 continuous covariates and 4 discrete covariates.

I am little confused as to how I test for association, for the discrete covariates, I used a chi sq test, testing at 95% if there is any association. However for the continuous covariates I don't know if I should be using two sample t-test  or anova test having fitted a linear model OR I should fit a GLM (binomial family) and see if the continuous covariate is significant in determining the outcome.

Please anyone able to explain to me which approach I should take and why it's the correct approach I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you start talking about 'outcome' variables or dependent variables or the like, I think you are into the modeling world. Chi-square tests for association and does not posit that one variable is dependent.  Similarly, the various kinds of correlation are tests of association.

Since your outcome is binary, the usual method is logistic regression

Comment: so if i wanted to test association between say outcome (success, failure) and a variable revision (yes,no), isn't chi qs correct test? 

And if i wanted to test association between outcome (success, failure) and variable time_of_revision (continuous), i should preform logistic regression then use anova or t-test?

Comment: If you want to test association, use a test of association. But then you don't have an outcome variable. If you have an outcome variable, use some form of regression. After you do logistic, you don't need to do ANOVA or t-test (and, in fact, ANOVA is inappropriate if the dependent variable is a dichotomy.

Comment: In addition to what Peter said, you have to consider whether unadjusted tests are appropriate.  Often they are not.  To do an adjusted (partial) test one usually needs multivariable models.  Think of a test of association (or partial association) as a test of flatness in a regression model.

Comment: Sorry am little confused, then it is not possible to test association by performing a GLM (using binomial family ) and looking to see if the variable is significant ?

Comment: The language isn't always consistently used. It does get confusing. A "test of association" refers to e.g. correlation and chi-square. However, the results of a regression are often described as association. This is mostly to avoid causal language. It might be better to use "related" for one and "associated" for the other ... but it will be confusing, regardless.   The main thing is that if you have a dependent variable, you probably want some form of regression.

Comment: To be explicit, a multivariable statistical model is usually the best way to perform a test of association.